# Existential Second Order Logic; Compactness and Löwenheim-Skolem

Tags: logic, compactness

I'm looking for proofs of Löwenheim-Skolem and Compactness in existential SoL.

I've spent a substantial amount of time on google, but can't seem to find anything!

Answer (score 1):

This easily follows from the respective results in first order logic by skolemization.

For example let $\varphi$ be an existential second order formula of vocabulary $\sigma$:
$$\varphi= \exists f_1\dots \exists f_n \exists R_1 \dots \exists R_m \psi$$

Consider a larger vocabulary $\overline{\sigma} = \sigma \cup \{f_1,\dots,f_n,R_1,\dots,R_m\}$ with new function and relation symbols.

Now let $\overline{\psi}$ be the first order $\overline{\sigma}$-formula arising by replacing all occurences of the variables $f_i$ and $R_i$ in $\psi$ with the corresponding function and relation symbols.

If $\varphi$ is satisfiable $\overline{\psi}$ is satisfiable. By the Löwenheim-Skolem-Theorem for first-order logic therefore satisfiable over a countable model. And so $\varphi$ is satisfiable over a countable model.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you!

Comment: Although, I'm not sure I can apply this method to compactness.

Comment: @swit compactness works the same way. If your set of formulas $\Phi$ is large you might get a large extended vocabulary, because you might want to add different symbols for each individual formula in $\Phi$. But then you create a copy $\Phi'$ in the same way. By first order compactness $\Phi'$ has a model iff all its finite subsets  have a model, this pulls back to $\Phi$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Sebastian.